# Kafka message not getting consumed

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a single Kafka node (v 0.10.2) running.We have configured log.retention.hours=480 but messages are not available to the consumers before the expiry time of the messages.(Ex message is pushed on 1st July and I have started my consumer on 4th July. Before starting the consumer I have verified messages are there through yahoo Kafka monitoring service. But on starting the consumer it keeps on polling and waiting for the messages).
Below mentioned are broker configuration :

```
broker.id=1
delete.topic.enable=true
num.network.threads=5
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=xxx
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=5
log.retention.hours=480
offsets.retention.minutes=43200
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=x.x.x.x:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=30000
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=30000
```

I have googled it but was not able to find the reason. Please let me know why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: can you add your consumer configuration?

Comment: missing consumer configuration, ie: `auto.offset.reset=earliest` to read from the beginning when you start your consumer otherwise it will read from the latest = records sent AFTER you started the consumer

Comment: Have you tried verifying by consuming using the kafka-console-consumer?

Answer (score 0):

There are some reasons why a message is not being consumed. Here are some ways you can debug:

One is as said, you might be consuming from the latest offset and hence you will be waiting. In this case, try producing the messages to the topic and check if they are consumed.

Next, ensure that your consumer subscribes to the partitions to which the messages are produced. If you are using Streams API then you need not worry about this since you will subscribe to all the partitions.

There could be some consumer configuration problem. Try consuming using the `kafka-console-consumer` with `--from-beginning` flag.
If there is no output means that the messages are probably not there or you have some difficulty connecting to it.
You can repeat this test both on the Kafka machine and from outside.

Check your connection from your consumer client to your broker which is the leader of the topic partitions you are consuming from. If there is a problem connecting to it, you must be getting an exception (like timeout for fetching the data).
*For this, you can use* `telnet broker_ip:port`

Sometimes, it may happen that your bootstrap-server may be accessible, but not the other brokers on which your topic partitions are lead.

Check your iptables rules to see if the brokers port is blocked or not. See
[What happens if the leader is not dead but unable to receive messages in Kafka? SPoF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55706589/what-happens-if-the-leader-is-not-dead-but-unable-to-receive-messages-in-kafka)